# How can I run a C program in Code::Blocks in Ubuntu?

Tags: code-blocks

I recently switched from Windows to Linux Ubuntu. I had been using CodeBlocks in Windows too. So I downloaded CodeBlocks from Software Manager. Now when I create a project and try to "Build and Run" it, it apparantly just compiles it and not run it. I started using Terminal to run the project. But from there I cannot use the math.h libraries or other imported stuff. Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that Code::Blocks doesn't execute your program after Build & Run because your project's compiler (from a project which was compiled in Windows?) and the IDE's default compiler don't match. Try compiling the project without running it using your Code::Blocks default compiler settings. Then try to run it again.

- Make sure you have GNU C compiler (*gcc*) installed.
- In Code::Blocks select *Settings* -> *Compiler…* -> *GNU GCC Compiler* (marked by mouse cursor in the below screenshot)

[image]